# How to switch transform origin according to transform requirement?

Tags: javascript, geometry, css-transforms

I have a div that is positioned absolutely. I want to dynamically change its width and apply a rotation transform.

When rotating I'd like the transform origin to be

```
transform-origin: center
```

When changing the width I'd like the transform origin to be

```
transform-origin: top left
```

My problem is when I change the transform-origin dynamically the position of the div jumps.

Is there a way to prevent the element from jumping position?

```js
let box = document.getElementById('box')
let width = document.getElementById('width')
let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate')

box.style.width = width.value + "px"; 

rotate.oninput = function() {
  box.style.transform = `rotate(${rotate.value}deg)`; 
}

width.oninput = function() {
    box.style.width = width.value + "px";  
}

width.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  box.style.transformOrigin = "top left"
})

rotate.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  box.style.transformOrigin = "center"
})
```

```css
#box {
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  width : <input type="range" min="10" max="300" value="50" class="slider" id="width">
</div>
  
<div class="slidecontainer">
  rotate: <input type="range" min="0" max="360" value="0" class="slider" id="rotate">
</div>
  
<div id="box"></div>
```